# Renaming Excel Active Sheet (using VSTO) disables "Add" button of WorkBook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, worksheet

I am working on a Excel Add-In project using VSTO with C#. I am trying to rename the active worksheet with name input by user. The code is very simple

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet; 
ws.Name="the new name of the Sheet";
```

However when the sheet gets renamed, the button to add new sheets gets disabled. If I close and reopen the Excel, the "Add" button is still disabled.
What gives ?

**Additional Info:** The button is in a custom tab in the Ribbon

Comment: Where is this button located in the Excel UI? On the worksheet? In the Ribbon? In a custom taskpane? If on the worksheet, please describe how it was created and linked to your VSTO code. Please click the EDIT link below your question and ADD THIS information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

How add button is created?
Who disabled this button at the first time?
The built-in 'new sheet' button won't be disabled when renaming a sheet.